# How to update app store apps programmatically in macOS?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm implementing a cleaner app, and one of its utilities is to keep tracking of applications' - which are installed by App Store - updates. That's fine. But I want to update the apps programmatically without interference from App Store.

Unfortunately I can't find any API to macOS App Store concerning this.

P.S: This is actually implemented in a famous cleaner app. If you would say this is not feasible.

Comment: https://github.com/mas-cli/mas